# Delete Cached Windows Network Share Passwords

Tags: windows, share-credentials

I have an XP/Pro computer which has some cached credentials for a network computer share it is trying to connect to.  While the credentials are correct enough to connect to the computer, I actually want to use a different set of credentials.

So the cached credentials are good enough to connect to \computer, but not \computer\share because that user account doesn't have permission.

Where are these cached credentials, and how might I change/remove them?

Comment: I think this should be called bug

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On Windows XP, click Start - Settings - Control Panel - User Accounts - Your username - Manage network passwords (on the left hand side).  You can add, edit and remove saved credentials here for accessing network resources here.

Comment: In Windows 7 this can be found at Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Credential Manager

Comment: Also, you need to reboot before Windows will completely forget a credential saved in this way.

Comment: @HernánEche Use English only, please. As a Spanish speaker, I think you're just making us look bad and most people here speak English.

Answer (score 6):

To delete locally cached credentials you can follow the below steps.

1. Open Run Window by clicking **Start -> Run** or click ‘**Windows key**’+‘**R**’.
2. In the text box, type the command **rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr** and click OK.
   **Note**:You can also type and run this command through Command Prompt.

   You could see the Stored Usernames and Passwords window after run the command.
3. To remove a saved credential you can select one of the entries and select Remove. A confirmation screen     will appear. Click on OK and the account will be removed
4. You can add additional saved passwords as well by clicking on the Add button and entering the                    appropriate information

Answer (score 1):

Try going to Control Panel -> User Accounts then click on the Advanced tab.  There is a button there that reads "Manage Passwords"  I believe these may be the credentials you are referring to.